# What type of board is this?

Tags: particle-board, osb

I saw this particle board used for a shop interior. It doesn't look like a standard OSB, the strands are thin and some of them are curved. I wonder if there is a more specific term for this type of board.

(the board in the picture is painted)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like wood fiber cement board to me

Example from https://www.architonic.com/en/product/selected-by-materials-council-wood-fibre-cement-board/1184351:

[image]

Google Image search for "wood fiber cement board" turns up many similar pictures

Comment: Looks like this is it. Thank you!

Comment: After some googling, also found this called "wood wool cement board".